# Permission denied warning on unlink

Tags: php, unlink, readdir

I am trying to a delete file selected using a dropdown. I am getting an error 'undefined index "file"' and permission denied warning on unlink.

```
<?php
$dirname = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."myphp/project/userdir/neeraj/";
$dir = opendir($dirname);
echo '<form action="delete.php" method="get">';
echo '<select name="file2">';
while(false != ($file = readdir($dir)))
{
    if(($file != ".") and ($file != ".."))
    {
        echo "<option value=".$file.">$file</option>";
    }
}
echo '</select>';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Delete" class="submit" />';
echo '</form>';?>  

            <?php
$dirpath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."myphp/project/userdir/neeraj/";
$file_to_delete = $_GET['file2'];
if ( unlink ($dirpath.'/'.$file_to_delete) ) {
    echo $file_to_delete . " deleted.";
} else {
    echo "Error.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Does the server has the right to access the files? Also, you're setting `$dirpath` with the same value than `$dirname`, why not reuse `$dirpath`?

Answer (score 0):

Note that your `$dirpath` ends with `/` and later you are trying to unlink:

```
unlink ($dirpath.'/'.$file_to_delete)
```

so it actualy gets something like this (note double slash):

```
[...] myphp/project/userdir/neeraj//$file_to_delete [...]
```

You should check file permissions to be sure that script has a right to unlink your files:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions

Answer (score 0):

I guess you get the first error because you do not wrap your code to be executed only on form submit. Change the second section of your code to this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['file2'])){ //i have posted my form
    $dirpath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."myphp/project/userdir/neeraj/";
    $file_to_delete = $_GET['file2'];
    if ( unlink ($dirpath.'/'.$file_to_delete) ) {
       echo $file_to_delete . " deleted.";
    } else {
       echo "Error.";
    }
}
?>
```

The other error is related to the apache user to be able or not to access and delete in the directory where you store the files.